# Android show a loading animation in layout

Tags: android, animation

In my application a progress dialog is shown when asyntask is running. but it fills screen so user cant do anything. I want to put an animation somewhere in layout. so while asyntask is runnnig animation shows up then disappears. 
I can do this via a textview. Textview becomes visible and writes "sending", when asyntask ends textview becomes unvisible. How can i do this with an animated gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an indeterminate `ProgressBar` in the center of your layout, make it visible in `onPreExecute()` and make it gone in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

First make a custom xml animation for loading in anim folder.

Instead of showing a TextView , you can show a view to which animation is set.
anyView.setAnimation(animation);

where animation is an object , you can initialize by using 
AnimationUtils.loadanimation(context, R.anim.your_anim);

and after the background process is done , set visibility of view to "gone".